# Inserir valores de uma variável no banco de dados com nodejs,mysql e sequelize

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados, node.js, api, sequelize-js

Estou tentando inserir no banco o conteúdo das variáveis: ***token*** e ***now***.
Os respectivos campos na tabela ***users*** do banco são: ***passwordResetToken*** e ***passwordResetExpires***.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu consigo retornar no console o valor das variáveis: **token** e **now**.

[image: Retorno do valor do token e now]

Eu estou tentando salvar esses dados nas tabelas: ***passwordResetToken*** e ***passwordResetExpires***.

Fazendo a lógica usando o ***Sequelize ORM***:

```
exports.forgotPassword = async (req, res) => {

sgMail.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);

const { email } = req.body;

try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ where: {email} });            //users table
    const token = crypto.randomBytes(20).toString('hex');
    const now = new Date();
    now.setHours(now.getHours() + 1);                             //1 HR valid token



    //error sequelize save datas in db
    await User.findByPk( user.id, {          //error-findByIdAndUpdate--mongo method - users table   { where: {email} } 
        '$set': { 
            passwordResetToken: token,
            passwordResetExpires: now,
        }
    });



    const msg = {
        to: email,
        from: 'apitest@api.com',     //    'apinet@gmail.com'
        subject: 'Sending with Twilio SendGrid is Fun',
        text: 'and easy to do anywhere, even with Node.js',
        html: token, email,         //'<strong>and easy to do anywhere fd, even with Node.js {token} </strong> {token}',
    };

    sgMail.send(msg);


    console.log(sgMail);
    console.log(token);
    console.log(now);


    res.status(200).json({

        Success: "Request sent successfully,check token in your email!"

    });

} catch (err) {

    res.status(400).send({ error: 'E-mail does not exist!' });
}
```

}

Todo processo é feito,porém não salva os valores de ***token*** e ***now*** nos campos ***passwordResetToken*** e ***passwordResetExpires*** na tabela ***users*** do banco.
O erro provável é aqui:

```
//error sequelize save datas in db
    await User.findByPk( user.id, {          //error-findByIdAndUpdate--mongo method - users table   { where: {email} } 
        '$set': { 
            passwordResetToken: token,
            passwordResetExpires: now,
        }
    });
```

Não tenho erro de resposta no console,porém os dois campos da tabela ***users*** não são salvos/update.
Na linha 114,esse ***$set*** veio da forma como se fazia com o ***mongodb***,e funcionava normal,agora migrando para ***mysql*** ***sequelize***,estou tentando fazer os dados serem inseridos no banco,porém ainda sem sucesso.

Alguma sugestão?

Desde já grato a todos!
Obrigado!

Comment: Por favor, edite a sua pergunta clicando em "**[edit]**" para trocar os códigos em imagem por texto. Como você pode ler [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%c3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485), código em imagem não é uma boa ideia.

Comment: Feito!Poderia me dar uma luz por gentileza?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvido!
Era só retirar o $set e adicionar o método update do sequelize.

```
await user.update({
        passwordResetToken: token,
        passwordResetExpires: now
       })
```